# Image impact on application memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, image, memory, arrays

i am trying to figure the memory usage impact of an image to an application. I am loading an image in memory from a byte array and i notice that the memory usage is not proportional to the image's size.

I have a byte array of 96389 bytes that i convert to an image in the following ways:

```
var actualImage = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(bytes));
var actualImage = Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes));
```

I would expect the application's memory usage to increase by an equal amount but in reality what happens is that the application's memory increases by 17324 kilobytes.

Why is this happening and how can i avoid using too much memory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656453/how-to-store-image-in-memory-more-compact-than-usual-bitmap-instance-and-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that your original picture is compressed. In uncompressed bitmap representation, an image uses 4 bytes per pixel (one for each channel red/green/blue, and one for alpha channel).

> How to avoid using too much memory?

It depends on what you're trying to do. Reduce the picture resolution, load only a portion of it, etc... But if you need to display the full picture at the original resolution, then there's no way to reduce the amount of memory used.

Comment: I guess i never had to think about that, compressed images i mean. Thank you for the pixel clarification. It actually makes sense because the image size is 2083 x 2083 = 4338889 pixels * 4 bytes/pixel = 17355556 bytes / 1000 = 17355 Kb approximately which is the memory increase i see in the applicaton. Thanks both to you and @usr for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the image stored in `bytes` is compressed. Images are not compressed in memory inside of the `Bitmap` class. Nothing you can do about that if you want to make use of the pixels.

Comment: The size of the image on disk is approximately the same as the byte array. I don't think the image is compressed, unless images on disk are compressed too.

Comment: Yes, they are likely compressed. Why does that surprise you? Most images are compressed. It is wasteful not to.